# Delphi idhttp long URL parameter is splittet automatically

Tags: delphi, post, indy, idhttp

I am using indys idhttp to submit an URL (post)

```
Procedure submit_post(url_string,EncodedStr:string;amemo:TMemo);
var
  aStream: TMemoryStream;
  Params: TStringStream;
begin
  aStream := TMemoryStream.create;
  Params := TStringStream.create('');

  try
    with Fmain.IdHTTP1 do
    begin
      Params.WriteString(EncodedStr);
      Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
      try
        Response.KeepAlive := False;
        Post(url_string, params, aStream);
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
          exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    aStream.WriteBuffer(#0' ', 1);
    aStream.Position := 0;
    amemo.Lines.LoadFromStream(aStream);
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  finally
    aStream.Free;
    Params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It works like a charm for me. I am trying to submit a URL (post) with a parameter containing 300 chars, but will be splittet automatically by adding an "&" every 90 chars. So the server only receives 90 chars instead of 300.

How can I submit an URL with a 300 character parameter without this automatic separation ?

Comment: Please add your url_string and EncodedStr contents, and the exact data that arrive at the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
function SubmitPost(Params:String): string;
const
  URL= 'http://xxxx.com/register.php?';
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Source,
  ResponseContent: TStringStream;
  I:Integer;
begin
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  lHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
  lHTTP.Request.Accept := '*/*';
  lHTTP.Request.Connection := 'Keep-Alive';
  lHTTP.Request.Method := 'POST';
  lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'OS Test User Agent';
  Source := TStringStream.Create(nil);
  ResponseContent:= TStringStream.Create;
  try
    try
      lHTTP.Post(URL+Params, Source, ResponseContent);
      Result := ResponseContent.DataString;
    except
      //your exception here
    end;
  finally
    lHTTP.Free;
    Source.Free;
    ResponseContent.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Usage

```
mmo1.Text := SubmitPost('Username=xxxx&Password=xxxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. My Post function works perfectly, but the URL is built by params coming from a memo line. With "WantReturns = FALSE", I can build a URL with the maximum line length of the memo. I guess 1024 characters per line which is okay for me.